# apply fadein() effect of jquery to php echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i would like to apply jquery fadein() effect to  what php echo displays..

```
   <?php 
    echo "Name";
   ?>
```

what is does simply display the "Name" within echo...but i want that "Name" to come up with an fadein() effect of jquery....

my code is like..

```
echo"<div id='title'>
             <span style='margin-top:1%; margin-left:3%;float:left;color: #3bb598'>campus name </span>
             <span style='margin-top:1%; margin-right:3%;float:right;color: #3bb598'>city</span>
             <br>
             <table><tr>
             <th><img src='rj.jpg' id='img' align='top'></th>
             <th>".$textid."</th>   
             </tr></table> 
             </div>
            ";
```

i want the result inside echo should come with a `fadein()` effect.

Comment: can you add an id or class to the parent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did. wrapped a div around my PHP code with id `fadein` and then used this jquery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#fadein').hide();
    $('#fadein').fadeIn();
});
```

Easy

Comment: just add div class/id to that echo statement and call with this function

Comment: <div id="fadein">ur echo statement</div>

Comment: $('#result').hide().html(data).fadeIn();

Answer (score 1):

in css, hide the id `title` with display:none;

This will hide the div without loading javascript, its better to use css here.

in jquery, use:

`$(function(){
$('#title').fadeIn();
});`

for fade speed, modify above code to `$('#title').fadeIn('time');` where time can be "slow","fast" or any number.